# loopback user model name conflict

Tags: loopbackjs

We are reviewing Loopback as a framework for establishing a RESTful API for our already existing MySQL database.

When using the StrongLoop Arc GUI for automatically discovering models based on our database, a conflict with the "user" table was reported.

The problem is that Loopback creates a default model named user, and our database has a table named user.

How do you recommend that we resolve this conflict?

Comment: If you want to keep your own user class, can you rename the table in MySQL?

Comment: We want to avoid that if at all possible -- we have some legacy code that has been in place for years that makes very heavy use of the table named User.

Comment: Could you duplicate the table? And perhaps add a trigger such that when oldtable is modified the new table is updated?

Comment: Also - remember that discovery is a one time event, right? Rename user to foo, do the discover, then drop the model completely and make your own user model (as per recommendations) that extends the core user and maps to the right table in mysql.

Comment: I believe this specifies how you could make a model and change the table it points to: https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/loopback-connector-mysql/1.1.0

Comment: Thanks for your input.  At the end of the day, we hope to use discovery to automatically create the proper our-user.json configuration file.  We want our user model to remain distinct from the built-in user model.  One time, using "loopback arc" our model got created (in spite of an error message).  But most of the time our user model is skipped.  We may need to investigate doing this programatically rather that using the arc utility.

Comment: I believe, stress believe, you can script the entire process and add conditional logic to handle your one special table. I'd start here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Discovering+models+from+relational+databases.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input.  The solution I have ended up implementing is to add a "my_user" table to our MySQL database that contains all of the same column definitions as the "user" table that is already present.  Then, when running the "slc arc" utility to create our data models, we "unselect" the User model from the list to process.  After this we adjust the entry in the my-user.json configuration file to change the table from my_user to user.  This has the effect that in the API context, our user model is known as MyUser but behind the scenes it is managed in the MySQL user table.

Comment: On the other hand, we add a data model named ApiUser to our API that extends the Loopback built in User model.  This way we are able to manage all authorized access to the API through the ApiUser model, while managing all of the things related to our MySQL database table named user through the data model named MyUser.

Comment: All of this hassle could have been avoided if the loopback built in model was not named "User" but was a name something like "LpbkUser" or there was some sort of name space convention where the table was named loopkack.User -- or if loopback would allow the user to select an alternative name when it detects a conflict with the User model when doing model discovery when using slc arc.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what you did. I work for IBM as a SL evangelist, so feedback like this is pretty important. :)